# Selecionar produtos mais vendidos de cada categoria

Tags: mysql

Olá

Tenho uma tabela com id, id_categoria, nome do produto e quantidade vendidas. Quero Listar os primeiros produtos vendidos de cada categoria, mesmo que o segundo ou terceiro produto da categoria "A" por exemplo  tenha vendido mais que o primeiro da catergoria"B", quero que apareça os primeiros de cada categoria!!!!

Comment: Adicione exemplo da sua tabela inicial e o resultado esperado. Leia este link https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484

Answer (score 1):

> quero que apareça os primeiros de cada categoria

Respondendo a pergunta acima....

---

Levando em consideração que sua tabela seja semelhante a tabela descrita abaixo:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_categoria | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nome         | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qnt_vendida  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Você pode utilizar a seguinte *query* para listar apenas o primeiro produto de cada categoria

```
SET sql_mode='';
SELECT id_categoria, nome FROM produtos GROUP BY id_categoria;
```

Ou ainda

```
SELECT id_categoria, ANY_VALUE(nome) FROM produtos GROUP BY id_categoria;
```

O [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) vai agrupar todos os valores idênticos da coluna "id_categoria", ou seja, ele vai retornar apenas os dados sem repeti-los e com isso nós conseguimos capturar os valores.

`SET sql_mode='';` e `ANY_VALUE` servem para evitar o erro [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). Esse erro é gerado quando você utiliza um valor não agregado em uma *query* que possui `GROUP BY`.

[**Demonstração**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be6200/2)

Comment: Excelente! Simples e eficaz.

Comment: @JoãoHaskel Caso tenha ajudado, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido. Qualquer coisa é só perguntar.